# PHP include(''); not displaying/running linked PHP

Tags: php, sorting, include

Can some please point out why this doesn't work? I have this include:

```
<?php include ('assets/images/Gallery/index.php'); ?>
```

In which contains PHP to run/display this:

```
<?php
  $images = glob('*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
  $num_of_files = 999999999;
  foreach($images as $image)
   {
     $num_of_files--;

     if($num_of_files > -1)
       echo "<li class='port2'><div class='wrap'><a href="."'".$image."'"." class='thickbox' rel='g'><img src="."'".$image."'"."><div class='mask'><span></span></div></a></div></li>" ;
     else
       break;
   }
?>
```

I’ve tried them side by side with different names and fresh documents and all I get is a blank screen. Alternatively, could someone, instead, tell me the right way to point the second, sort script, to the directory of my choosing, rather than including it from the directory I need it in. Thank you.

**EDIT:** As Fred-ii confirmed, he was able to it running. I too, now know it is linking to the second PHP file, as its now throwing this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in assets/images/gallery/index.php on line 4
```

Line 4 reads:

```
foreach($images as $image)
```

Comment: Worked fine for me. If you're running your code from within a folder that doesn't contain images, that will explain the blank screen.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Fred-ii-, ill have to look further. Appreciate you having a look

Comment: @Fred-ii- , I have edited my post, as i now see it linking to my PHP file within the gallery directory, because its now throwing an error. All i changed was the capital letter on Gallery to lowercase. Any ideas whats wrong with line 4?

Comment: The only way `glob()` can return anything other than an array is if it encounters an error.

Comment: I suspect the problem here is the include path. The included file `assets/images/Gallery/index.php` will **not** behave as if it was running in the `assets/images/Gallery` folder, because it is being included from somewhere else.

Comment: On certain systems, lettercase is important. `gallery` and `Gallery` are not the same thing. I also noticed `class='thickbox'` --- Are you trying to use this as a Wordpress plugin, or jQuery plugin? @Aquious

Comment: Hi @Phil, The gallery PHP file performs as it should when i navigate to it via a browser, but not when im including it.

Comment: Plus, as Havenard mentioned, it seems to be a path issue. Have you tried `<?php include ('/assets/images/Gallery/index.php'); ?>` yet that doesn't always work. @Aquious

Comment: You can also add `phpinfo();` inside your file to see what the actual path is that the file is using.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, correct im trying to use jQuery. The idea being that each time a file is uploaded, the PHP lists them by newest date, them spits it out in a gallery format. ie (i have the  include between <ul> tags)

Comment: So this isn't the actual code you're using then.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes this is the code I'm using to change existing code. If I write `<li><a href="#"><img src"#" /></a></li>` manually, where i have the include, everything woks fine. I'm trying to automate it so i can upload an image via ftp and have it displayed at the top of the list

Comment: Ok. So have you tried `<?php include ('/assets/images/Gallery/index.php'); ?>` adding a `/` ? May be a path issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes i tried that. I have it working if i add everything to the root folder. Can you tell me the correct way to change the dir location via `$images = glob('*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: I figured out how to get around it, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Try replacing this whole block `$images = glob('*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE); $num_of_files = 999999999; foreach($images as $image)` with 
`$path = 'images/'; foreach (glob($path."/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT) as $image){` (**images/** being the folder you wish to use as an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the inluded script, within my main index.php and then changing the directory location as below:

```
<?php
  $images = glob('assets/images/gallery/*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
  $num_of_files = 999999999;
  foreach($images as $image)
  {
    $num_of_files--;

    if($num_of_files > -1)
    echo "<li class='port2'><div class='wrap'><a href="."'".$image."'"." class='thickbox' rel='g'><img src="."'".$image."'"."><div class='mask'><span></span></div></a></div></li>" ;
 else
   break;
 }
?>
```

Im still not sure why i could not include it from its gallery location but this got me out of trouble. Basically the script will display images in upload date order.

Thank you @Fred-ii- for his help in the matter. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I dont want to mark this answer as the correct solution as i have just used a work around that worked for me.

Comment: That was another option I was going to suggest `glob('assets/images/gallery/` but you can mark your own answer and accept it once SO let's you in order to close the question.

Comment: Did you happen to try [`my suggestion`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545160/php-include-not-displaying-running-linked-php?noredirect=1#comment36146333_23545160)? That's what I use.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, No i havent tried it yet but i have kept a copy to refer to after this project as i would like to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with your error message, just do this to check if `$images` does indeed have content like this:

```
if (!empty($images)) {
```

Here it is integrated into your code:

```
<?php
  $images = glob('*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
  $num_of_files = 999999999;
  if (!empty($images)) {
    foreach($images as $image) {
     $num_of_files--;

     if($num_of_files > -1)
       echo "<li class='port2'><div class='wrap'><a href="."'".$image."'"." class='thickbox' rel='g'><img src="."'".$image."'"."><div class='mask'><span></span></div></a></div></li>" ;
     else
       break;
   }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. Using your additions, i now receive a blank box rather than an error. Yet if i navigate to the PHP file in the gallery folder, it performs as it should, displaying images in upload order.